# Login is not being called before each test case i.e it() when written inside Onprepare() in config.js

Tags: protractor

I am new to Protractor and implemented login functionality inside conf.js.

```
var env = require('./environment.js');

// This is the configuration file showing how a suite of tests might
// handle log-in using the onPrepare field.
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: env.seleniumAddress,

  framework: 'jasmine',

  specs: [
    'login/login_spec.js'
  ],

  capabilities: env.capabilities,

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl + '/ng1/',

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '/ng1/login.html');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('clickme')).click();

    // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
    // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
    // index.html.
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        return /index/.test(url);
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
};
```

But this executes only before any of test case execution starts, as per details of the link for login functionality it should work before each it(,) block.
"Another option is to put your log-in code into an onPrepare function, which will be run once before any of your tests".

So is this OnPrepare intended for execution only once,which is before any of Test case[it()] starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several functions that can be used before it() and before test suites

---

**onPrepare()**

- Part of your conf.js file
- Runs at before a spec file is called, only running once per test, but will run on all test

**beforeAll()**

- Part of a spec.js file
- Runs at the beginning of a test, but will only execute on the spec file it is written in

**beforeEach()**

- Part of a spec.js file
- Runs before every it() block, and will only execute on it()s within the spec file

**afterAll()**

- Part of spec.js file
- Runs at the end of test, only execute inside spec file

**afterEach()**

- Part of spec.js file
- Runs after every it() block, and will only run after its in spec file

---

If you need your login to happen before every it() block then **beforeEach()** is your best solution, while if you only need to login once per spec file, then **beforeAll()** will work on a per test basis, while **onPrepare()** will work on a global basis

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben. Mostly i wrong interpreted there words for OnPrepare. I am implementing in beforeAll(), but i have one more question for you,                           
                                                                                                                               
 1.will it() blocks execute serially ? 2. why does anything written in beforeAll() doesnt display in report?3. If i want to have login written in beforeAll() is this right way? 4. Also can you tell me where should we look for all functions related to Jasmine? i referred to their introduction.html.

Comment: @radhajanagouda 1) Yes. 2) In order to get my beforeAll to display in a report, I use console.log() to output some info. Its not the best solution but it works for me 3) beforeAll is a good spot for login stuff 4) [Jasmine Documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/global)

Comment: If you wan't more in depth answers probably best to ask new question